# Remove anonymous event listeners before adding any new ones

Tags: javascript

EDIT : I need to invoke one function which fetches data and reloads the page's contents. But this has to be invoked once another function has fetched data(webSql). I cannot use the WebSql callback as variables are out of scope. So I created a custom Event and added a listener in the second function scope. So when data is fetched I am dispatching the event in the first function scope. Now the issue if the page was reloaded more than once, listeners will get added multiple times and all will be invoked which I dont want.

I need to make sure that only one function is listening to a custom event. Right now am removing the listener once its invoked like this :

```
document.addEventListener("customEvent", function () {
  actualCallBack(var1, var2); // Since I need to pass parameters I need to use callBack within an anonymous function.
  this.removeEventListener("customEvent", arguments.callee, false);
}, false);
```

But the problem is anonymous function will be removed only after its invoked in the first place. There is a possibility of listener getting added mulitple times. How can I remove event listeners before adding a new one ?

```
document.removeEventListener("customEvent");
document.addEventListener(...);
```

I could have removed it, if a variable function was used instead, but I need to pass some parameters to callback so I need to use anonymous functions.

Comment: IIRC, `cloneNode` clones everything but event listeners. Doing that in `document`-scope may be hilarious, though..

Comment: One way would be to put the whole event binding in a custom function. That function can then keep a reference to the passed handler and make sure that only one handler is bound. Of course that requires that the handler is only bound to the element via that function.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation why you have to use an anonymous function. Here is a related question btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object

Comment: @FelixKling Am not binding events to div elements. Am invoking event listeners using `dispatchEvent` in another function. So I need to remove anything which was added before.

Comment: @basilikum I have edited question. I need to pass some parameters so I am wrapping the callBack within an anonymous function.

Comment: @2-Stroker, could you explain your use case a bit more? We could figure out a better solution than a generic "remove anonymous listeners" thing.

Comment: @Dogbert I have edited the question, added more detail.

Comment: @2-Stroker, check out my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using felix's suggestion

```
var setSingletonEventListener = (function(element){
    var handlers = {};
    return function(evtName, func){
        handlers.hasOwnProperty(evtName) && element.removeEventListener(evtName, handlers[evtName]);
        if (func) {
            handlers[evtName] = func;
            element.addEventListener(evtName, func);
        } else {
            delete handlers[evtName];
        }
    };
})(document);

setSingletonEventListener("custom event", function(){

});

//replaces the previous
setSingletonEventListener("custom event", function(){

});

//removes the listener, if any
setSingletonEventListener("custom event");
```

Comment: Tried this out, but it gets called twice. Perhaps I did something wrong -- Fiddler Link http://jsfiddle.net/NeT7W/1/

Comment: @2-Stroker: Fixed the code, it had to be `element.removeEventListener(evtName, handlers[evtName])`.

Comment: How to pass a custom DOM element if we don't want to listen on `document`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
var singletonEventListenerFor = function (element, eventName) {
    var callback = null;
    element.addEventListener(eventName, function () {
        callback && callback();
    });
    return function (set) {
        callback = set;
    };
};
```

Testing:

```
var event = document.createEvent("Event");
event.initEvent("customEvent", true, true);

var listener = singletonEventListenerFor(document, "customEvent");

var counter = 0;

listener(function () {
    console.log(++counter);
});

// counter === 1
document.dispatchEvent(event);

// Remove the listener
listener();
// This shouldn't increment counter.
document.dispatchEvent(event);

listener(function () {
    console.log(++counter);
});

// counter === 2
document.dispatchEvent(event);
// counter === 3
document.dispatchEvent(event);

console.log('3 === ' + counter);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/2zUZT/

API could be improved by returning an object with `.set(callback)` and `.remove()` functions instead of using a single function to do both things, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Store somewhere that you've already applied the listener, and only add it, if it hasn't been added already.

Comment: Could have used this, but in my case the only persistent variable would be that in web Sql DB.