# SharePoint 2013 - save button in the ribbon - cancel saving if form not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to perform some validation when a user click the save button on the SharePoint ribbon and cancel the submission of the form if it is not valid.

I am using a page layout in SharePoint 2013. The fields come from the page layout content type.

The id of the button is `Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit-SelectedItem`

I tried without success:

- add an onclick handler on the button

  ```
  var saveButton = function () {
      return document.getElementById("Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit-SelectedItem");
  }
  $(saveButton()).removeAttr("onclick");
  $(saveButton()).click(
      function(ev){
          ev.preventDefault();
          ev.returnvalue=false; // for IE only
          return false;
      }
  );
  ```
- replace the onsubmit attribute of the form

  ```
  $("form").attr("onsubmit","javascript: return false;")
  ```

Both codes are happily ignored by sp2013!

Comment: If we are talking about standard SharePoint list forms then there is built in PreSaveAction function. Check this post http://hannanazam.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-apps-custom-validation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel the event, instead of targeting the link, I have targeted the img inside the link. My javascript code is then fired before the SharePoint javascript.

```
$("#Ribbon\\.EditingTools\\.CPEditTab\\.EditAndCheckout\\.SaveEdit-SelectedItem img").click(function(){
    console.log("saveButton clicked");
    return false;
});
```

The double antislashes are meant to tell jquery this is no class name but a dot in the id.

Another problem arised: the save button can take a few seconds to load, so we have to wait before attaching the click handler. Finally the code is like this:

```
//namespace
var qp = {}
// attaching a click handler to the save button image
qp.registerSaveButtonEvent = function() {
    var b = "#Ribbon\\.EditingTools\\.CPEditTab\\.EditAndCheckout\\.SaveEdit-SelectedItem img";
    // if the button exists
    if ($(b).length > 0) {
        // we attach the click handler to it
        $(b).click(function(){
            console.log("saveButton clicked");
            return false;
        });
        // we stop the future calls of this function
        clearInterval(qp.interval);
    }
}
// Running the function every 500 ms
qp.interval = setInterval(qp.registerSaveButtonEvent, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to override a button in the ribbon you must be sure that:

1. The button is loaded

   On this matter Sharepoint 2013 and 2010 require a slight different code.
   According to the blog post [SharePoint 2013: Trigger Event With Ribbon Tab Changes](https://sanmaziri.wordpress.com/2015/05/21/sharepoint-2013-trigger-event-with-ribbon-tab-changes/) you need to fire an event and process it in your code. For Sharepoint 2010 check [Trigger an event whenever the SharePoint 2010 ribbon changes](https://spmonkeypoint.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/trigger-an-event-whenever-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-changes/)
   .
2. All the events attached to the button are intercepted.

   I noticed that not only `click` event is used by Sharepoint but even the `mousedown`, so it's better to include both in the new event handler. You would add a class to avoid multiple handlers to be attached. I suggest to use the container because otherwise if user click in the surrounding area the standard event handler is fired.
   Indeed the only safe way to [remove all the handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object) is to clone the element and replace it with its clone.

So this is the code I finally assembled:

```
// 1) Fires 'ribbontabselected' every time the ribbon selection changes
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

  // Sometime this function is called twice on IE, don't ask why...
  // So better safe than sorry.
  if (typeof CUI.Ribbon.prototype.$1q_0_old == 'undefined') {
    CUI.Ribbon.prototype.$1q_0_old = CUI.Ribbon.prototype.$1q_0;
  }
  
  CUI.Ribbon.prototype.$1q_0 = function () {
    this.$1q_0_old();
    $(document).trigger('ribbontabselected', [this.get_selectedTabCommand()]);
  };
}, 'cui.js');

// 2) Fires 'ribbontabselected' after the ribbon has been initialized after load
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  var pm = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
  pm.add_ribbonInited(function () {
    $(document).trigger('ribbontabselected', [SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_ribbon().get_selectedTabCommand()]);
  });
}, 'sp.ribbon.js');

// Identify the button (use the container as selector)
// Double antislashes to tell jquery this is no class name but a dot in the id
var sharepointExcelButtonHandler = 'a#Ribbon\\.List\\.Actions\\.ExportToSpreadsheet-Large';

// 3. Modify command button
$(document).on('ribbontabselected', function (e, selectedTabCommand) {

  if (selectedTabCommand == 'ListTab' && $(sharepointExcelButtonHandler).length > 0) {
    if (! $(sharepointExcelButtonHandler).hasClass("DIST-excel-download-processed")) {

      // The only safe way to remove all previous handlers is to replece the element with a clone
      $(sharepointExcelButtonHandler)
       .replaceWith($(sharepointExcelButtonHandler).clone());

      // Add new handlers
      $(sharepointExcelButtonHandler)
        .addClass("DIST-excel-download-processed")
        .on("mousedown click", function(e) {
          console.log("Do your stuff");
          return false;
        });
    }
  }
});
```