# Removed HTML element. What is the easiest way to get it back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In my main page I have a simple form. I have made it so I when the user clicks the "submit" button I send the form data to the server side and also just after submit I remove the form using Jquery. However, I would like to have a way so that when I click a button after geting the form removed it would appear again exactly as it was before geting removed.

When I click the form submit button I don't want the form to be invisible; I want the form to be removed from the page. Do I have to make a new form everytime I remove it to be exactly as the removed one or is there a way to get it back when clicking the "recovering" button?

Just in case, I am using JADE for rendering some other stuff... I am not sure if it is needed for this. Sorry for any mistakes, I am quite newbie in programming. I can give more information if needed.

Comment: One way to do it would be to clone the form before deleting it. When you want it back you can just say **`$(parent).append(formClone)`**. Or you can just set **`display: none`** instead of deleting it I guess...

Comment: Or instead of removing it you could append it to a newly created node _not in the document_, then append it back to the document later.

Comment: Just like @ZakariaAcharki said.

Comment: @AngelPolitis You can lose information by cloning.

Comment: @AngelPolitis [Cloning (with `.cloneNode()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and replacing element with a clone is a good way to [remove all event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object) for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is) to check if element is in `document`, [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach)

```js
var div = $("div");
$("button").click(function() {
  if (div.is("button + div")) div.detach();
  else div.insertAfter(this)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>toggle div</button>
<div>abc</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just hide the form when you submit, then show it when you want by clicking `recover` button :

```js
$('#my-submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#my-form').hide(); //Hide the form
})

$('#recover').on('click', function(){
  $('#my-form').show(); //Show the form
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  First name : <input name="f_name"/>
  <br>
  Last name : <input name="l_name"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value='Submit' id="my-submit"/>
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" id='recover'>Recover</button>
```

Hope this helps.

---

Or you could also clone the form before submit using `.clone(true)` (*The `true` indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well*) , then show it when user click on `recuver` button :

```js
var my_form="";

$('#my-submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  my_form = $('#my-form').clone(true); //Save the form
  $('#my-form').remove();
})

$('#recover').on('click', function(){
  $('body').prepend(my_form); //Show the form
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  First name : <input name="f_name"/>
  <br>
  Last name : <input name="l_name"/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value='Submit' id="my-submit"/>
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" id='recover'>Recover</button>
```

Comment: _"I don't the form to be invisible; I want the form to be removed from the page"_

Comment: @guest271314 That may be what the user request, but the sure way to have it exactly as it was before and the best way to do it is hide/show.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek `.detach()` preserves data and events plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/VTaRXAsXoAiwVTiy7yh7?p=preview

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes, though requirement described at OP is to remove element from `document`, not toggle `display` property of element

Comment: Yes I see, thanks for your intervention, already added the `clone(true)` solution...

Answer (score 2):

Just save the element to a JS variable before removing the element, e. g.:

```
var form = document.getElementById('example-form');
form.parentNode.removeChild(form); // The form is removed.
```

Then you will be able to insert the element into document again, e. g.:

```
someElement.appendChild(form); // The form is restored.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you would like to `show / hide` particular element.

IMO, the  `toggle()` would be the best option.

```
$('div').toggle();
```

[Toggle Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

If you want to remove it from DOM, you can use remove / detach as well.

`$( "p" ).detach();` or `$( "p" ).remove();`

```js
var p;
$('button').click(function(){
  if ( p ) {
    p.appendTo( "body" );
    p = null;
  } else {
    p = $( "p" ).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
p
{
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Comment: _"I don't the form to be invisible; I want the form to be removed from the page"_

Comment: @guest271314 See, I've updated my answer remove / attached, will be the best option.

Comment: _"See, I've updated my answer remove / attached, will be the best op"_ How is updated Answer different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39678682/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39678783/) Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 I know nothing is so new in my answer, but I just show you a way to use toggle which is the most simplest method for show/hide any element, but if you wants to remove element from DOM, you have to use remove / detach method, as I've mentioned in the example also.