# Remove all listener of "document" element

Tags: javascript

I have tried to imitate some examples, but in my case it does not work, it may seem like another question but I have not really been able to solve it.

I have some listeners in my document.

```
    document.addEventListener("clmtrackrNotFound", function(event) {
        //bla bla
    }, false);

   // detect if tracker loses tracking of face
    document.addEventListener("clmtrackrLost", function(event) {
        //bla bla
    }, false);

    // detect if tracker has converged
    document.addEventListener("clmtrackrConverged", function(event ) {
   },false)
```

This is repeated every time I access the .js file. How can I remove them all?

Comment: @BobKruithof this answer not answered my problem. I have all my event listeners in "document" element..

Comment: Please read all answers on above question, there is an answer which answers your question.
To be specific here
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object#answer-42377541

Comment: @shreyastigdi not works for me.. getEventListeners is not defined. I had already tried.

Comment: I see a lot of answers in the mentioned post, even for removing the eventListeners of the document.