# JavaScript remove an IIFE event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to remove click events from a list of id's after adding them with an IIFE like this

```
function setupPlayer(player){
  var squareState = {};
  for (i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
      if(allSquares[i].innerHTML === "") {
        // set up a click event for each square
         document.getElementById(allSquares[i].getAttribute('id')).addEventListener('click', (clickSquare)(i));
      }
    }
}
```

The clickSquare function returns

```
function clickSquare(i){
  var num = i;
  return function() {
      document.getElementById(allSquares[num].getAttribute('id')).innerHTML=player;
  }
}
```

Then I try to remove them with

```
function removeClickEvents(){
  for (let i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(allSquares[i].getAttribute('id')).removeEventListener('click', clickSquare);
  }
}
```

I've tried naming the returned anonymous function and using  `removeEventListener` on that to no avail.

Comment: You either remove all (isn't there an API function to remove _all_ events listeners?), or you need to keep a pointer to the actual function. Sending in the function.creating function is useless - that's an entirely different pointer (to a different function object). There is no magic or crystal ball:The event system simply stores all callback function pointers in a structure and when you remove one tries to find the one you send in for removal in that structure. Also seee https://stackoverflow.com/a/4386514/544779

Comment: What are the elements of `allSquares` array? Are there elements with duplicate `id` within the `document`? What is purpose of `document.getElementById(allSquares[i].getAttribute('id'))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove event listener from a DOM element you need to pass the same function you used while adding event listener, as the parameter.

In javascript when you create an object it creates a new instance of that object class, so it won't be equal to another object even if it is created with same parameters

Example:

```
{} != {} // returns true
[] != [] // returns true
```

Same goes with function, whenever you write `function (){}` it creates a new instance of `Function` class.

Example:

```
function a() {
    return function b() {}
}
a() != a() // returns true
```

**Solution:**

So for you to be able to remove the event listeners, you will have to store the functions you have passed to `addEventListener`

```
var listeners = [];

function setupPlayer(player) {
    var squareState = {};
    for (i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
        if(allSquares[i].innerHTML === "") {
            listeners[i] = clickSquare(i);
            document.getElementById(allSquares[i].getAttribute('id')).addEventListener('click', listeners[i]);
        }
    }
}

function clickSquare(i) {
    var num = i;
    return function() {
        document.getElementById(allSquares[num].getAttribute('id')).innerHTML=player;
    }
}

function removeClickEvents() {
    for (let i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
        if(listeners[i]) {
            document.getElementById(allSquares[i].getAttribute('id')).removeEventListener('click', listeners[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

From your code where you are using

```
document.getElementById(allSquares[i].getAttribute('id'))
```

I am assuming that `allSquares[i]` is a DOM element already, your code can be more simplified

```
var listeners = [];

function setupPlayer(player) {
    var squareState = {};
    for (i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
        if(allSquares[i].innerHTML === "") {
            listeners[i] = clickSquare(i);
            allSquares[i].addEventListener('click', listeners[i]);
        }
    }
}

function clickSquare(i) {
    var num = i;
    return function() {
        allSquares[num].innerHTML=player;
    }
}

function removeClickEvents() {
    for (let i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
        if(listeners[i]) {
            allSquares[i].removeEventListener('click', listeners[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is being called immediately at `(clickSquare)(i)`. At code at Question `allSquares` appears to be the element itself, `clickSquare` function can be referenced directly and `event.target` can be used within event handler to reference the current element in `allSquares` collection

```js
let player = 123;

setInterval(() => player = Math.random(), 1000);

onload = () => {

  let allSquares = document.querySelectorAll("div[id|=square]");


  let button = document.querySelector("button");

  button.onclick = removeClickEvents;

  function setupPlayer(player) {
    var squareState = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
      if (allSquares[i].innerHTML === "click") {
        // set up a click event for each square
        allSquares[i].addEventListener('click', clickSquare);
      }
    }
  }

  function clickSquare(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    event.target.innerHTML = player;
  }

  function removeClickEvents() {
    for (let i = 0; i < allSquares.length; i++) {
      allSquares[i].removeEventListener('click', clickSquare);
    }
  }



  setupPlayer(player);

}
```

```html
<div id="square-0">click</div>
<div id="square-1">click</div>
<div id="square-2">click</div>

<button>remove events</button>
```