# can websites block me from using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, console

So I have used this function to scroll down to other pages it works fine. But when it tries to use this function on this website Www.holonis.com and then click on my follower's list go down. It would not let me go down. The page just stays the same nothing Changes can someone please help me. Btw here is the script that I'm using

```js
function autoScrolling() {window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);}setInterval(autoScrolling,500);
```

Comment: Maybe they are listening scroll event and preventing the default action.

Comment: Thanks for the help but Is there a way to get passed this?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the page source, the code adds an event listener to document.body

This code fixed it but who knows what else it breaks in the process:

```
element.outerHTML = element.outerHTML;
```

Taken from [Javascript/DOM: How to remove all events of a DOM object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object)