# How can I use removeClickEvents if my events are added with a for loop? [javascript]

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am creating a tic-tac-toe game where I add event listeners to check if a box is clicked. Here is the function I am using to add click events to elements on my page:

```
function addClickEvents(){
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].addEventListener(
      "click",
      function () {
        addEvents(i);
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  }
}

function addEvents(x) {
  document.images[x].style.display = "block";
}
```

I would like to remove these events so I don't overlap them once the game is reset. I have a separate button on the page that resets the game. Is there anyway to remove the eventListeners using that button? I have used a function that looks like this but it does not seem to work:

```
function resetGame() {
  for (let reset = 0; reset < 9; reset++) {
    document.boxes[reset].removeEventListener("click", addEvents);
  }
}
```

I have also tried to attach the function to a variable and add it that way, but this does not work as far as i know since I need to pass a variable into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a common class to your boxes elements and then use them later in the code to remove the event listeners.

First you will add class like:

```
function addClickEvents(){
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].classList.add('boxes');// add class to the boxes
    boxes[i].addEventListener(
      "click",
      function () {
        addEvents(i);
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can write reset function like:

```
function resetGame() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.boxes').forEach((box)=>{
    box.outerHTML = box.outerHTML;// This will remove all event listeners
 })
}
```

For more information you can look at  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026635/3210199)