# how to removeEventLister on anonymous function without name assigned

Tags: javascript

Now I'm practicing Javascript and I need some helps from you guys.

https://codepen.io/domrongpon-tanpaibul/pen/YzGyBZq?editors=1111

```js
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close-dlg', {cancelable: true}))) {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

I think the solution is to use `removeEventLister` but the problem is I need it on anonymous function without assigning function name.

Are there any solutions to solve this?

Comment: Couldn’t you store your function in a variable, if you want to remove this specific listener only?

Comment: What the above comment said or just don't make it anonymous.

Comment: *"I need it on anonymous function without assigning function name"* Why do you *need* this? There is no difference between a named and an unnamed function at runtime (at least as far as the JavaScript engine is concerned).

Comment: Yeah the solution is just naming the handler function.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-event-listeners-of-a-dom-object

Comment: sadly that quiz rule's  not to  modify anythings on parent class (assign as variable, assign function name )

Comment: So you are asking us to solve the quiz for you? That seems to defeat the purpose of doing the quiz in the first place.