# How to remove a specific click event handler attached to an dynamically generated HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The code below creates a new button element with the text "Download" and an ID of "download", and appends it as a child element of the element with an ID of "container".

When the button is clicked the container's onclick is also triggered. I tried to remove it with
`removeEventListener()` without success.

```
document.getElementById('download').removeEventListener("onclick", myclick); 
document.getElementById('download').removeEventListener("click", myclick);
document.getElementById('download').removeEventListener("click", myclick, true);


function cleanup(elem) {
    for (let t in elem) if (t.startsWith('on') && elem[t] != null) {
        elem[t] = null;
        console.log('cleanup removed listener from '+elem.nodeName,t);
    } 
    for (let t of elem.all_handlers || []) {
        elem.removeEventListener(t.typ, t.fn, t.opt);
        console.log('cleanup removed listener from '+elem.nodeName,t.typ);
    } 
}


var el = document.getElementById('download');
cleanup(el);
```

I also tried all of those [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-event-listeners-of-a-dom-object) and none of them removed the onclick. (e.g. cloning etc.)
PS: the HTML code cannot be modified because it's part of a framework.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').append(
        $(document.createElement('button')).prop({
            type: 'button',
            innerHTML: 'Download',
            id : 'download'
        })
    );
   // I placed the code to remove the event listener here
});

function myclick(e) {

   console.log('myclick');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html id="container" onclick="myclick(event)">
</html>
```

Comment: The main problem here is that button "download" actually doesn't have an event listener. Clicking the button triggers myclick because it's on html (#container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to prevent myclick function to be called when the button is pressed, you can actually add onclick event to the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').append(
        $(document.createElement('button')).prop({
            type: 'button',
            innerHTML: 'Download',
            id : 'download'
        })
    );
    $("#download").on("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevents myclick being triggered
        console.log('myclick btn'); // other possible code you want..
    })
});

function myclick(e) {

   console.log('myclick');

}
```

Comment: Thanks, e.stopPropagation(); did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the eventlistener from #download, shouldn't you remove it from #container?

```
$("#container").prop("onclick", null).off("click");
```

or

```
document.getElementById('container').onclick = null;
```

Comment: onclick of the container itself should not be removed

Answer (score 0):

Removing the event listener for the parent element isn't the best way to do this. Instead, the child element's event listener should call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up to parent elements. I recommend reading up online about Event Bubbling in JavaScript.

Comment: The question has already been answered by Ivan Gajic. Thanks anyway.